# Adapt Element in Viewport function to work in IOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, css

I'm using this function to determine if an element is visible in the viewport,

```
var elementInViewport = function(el) {
    var top = el.offsetTop;
    var left = el.offsetLeft;
    var width = el.offsetWidth;
    var height = el.offsetHeight;
    while (el.offsetParent) {
      el = el.offsetParent;
      top += el.offsetTop;
      left += el.offsetLeft;
    }
    return (
      top >= window.pageYOffset &&
      left >= window.pageXOffset &&
      (top + height) <= (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) && (left + width) <= (window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth)
    );
}
```

Which seems to be working perfectly in All Desktop browsers and Android, but sometimes it's returning false when the element is 100vh in IOS devices ( and it's actually in the viewport )

I believe this issue is for the Safari's fixed bars ( in top and bottom )

( As some times the window.innerHeight is different, depending the scroll position )

But I don't know how to calculate those heights and when exactly to substract them...

Any hint ?